# how do i pass parameters to subset()?

Tags: r

I am building a gui which lets me select a subset of a data.frame by clicking on the various factor names.
After having received user input, how do i pass it to the subset function?

e.g.: I have a dataframe df with factors MORNING and EVENING in column timeofday and RECEIVE and SEND in column optype. From the GUI I know that the user wants to a subset containing only RECEIVE operations, so i have the following strings as well:

RequestedFactor1 which equals "optype"
RequestedRelationship1 equals "=="
RequestedValue1 which equals "RECEIVE"

What can i do to those strings to pass them to subset, so that I will receive the same output as if i had called **subset(df,optype=="RECEIVE")** ?

TIA

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this you can use an eval-parse construct, but again I warn that this is actually tricky business. Please read the help files about these two very carefully. So in your case this becomes :

```
subset(df,eval(parse(text=paste(RF1,RR1,RV1))))
```

An example to illustrate some tricky parts :

```
> RF1 <- "optype"

> RR1 <- "=="

> RV1 <- "\"RECEIVE\""

> optype <- c("RECEIVE","Not")

> ifelse(eval(parse(text=paste(RF1,RR1,RV1))),1,0)
[1] 1 0
```

Mind the escaped quote-marks (\"). This is necessary as you want to test against a string, and not the RECEIVE object. Alternatively you can do :

```
> RF1 <- "optype"

> RR1 <- "=="

> RV1 <- "Text"

> optype <- c("RECEIVE","Not")

> Text <- "RECEIVE"

> ifelse(eval(parse(text=paste(RF1,RR1,RV1))),1,0)
[1] 1 0
```

Comment: Thank You! Should have thought of it.

Answer (score 4):

The comparison operators in R are actually special functions, so you can use do.call to run the functions, no need for eval and parse and the potential headaches that can come from there.  e.g.:

```
rf1 <- 'Species'
rr1 <- '=='
rv1 <- 'setosa'

subset(iris, do.call(rr1, list( get(rf1), rv1 ) ) )
```

You need to "get" the variable so that you have the variable value rather than the name, the rest can be the character strings.

Comment: Not real need to use subset at all - `iris[match.fun(rr1)(iris[[rf1]], rv1), ]`